# C#, trouble with SQLreader/command

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sqlcommand

I have some trouble with the `SqlDataReader`:

```
public string GetVareNavn(string streg)
    {
        string navn = "";
        SqlConnection myCon = DBcon.getInstance().conn();

        string query =
            "SELECT Navn FROM Vare WHERE Stregkode = ) Values('" + streg + "')";

        myCon.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
        Console.WriteLine("navn: "+navn);
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            navn = dr.GetString(1);
        }
        myCon.Close();
        return navn;
    }
```

It throws an exception at `com.ExecutiveReader();` and the exception is:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I don't know why this one doesn't work right now, because I've used it in another project.

Comment: I think you should learn SQL so that you can correctly create SQL statements. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks like it was copied from something that used to be an `INSERT` statement; you don't need the `VALUES...` clause at the end of the statement. Try changing your `query` to:

```
string query =
    "SELECT Navn FROM Vare WHERE Stregkode = @streg";
```

Then modify this code to use the parameter:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streg", streg);
```

Comment: Thank you both. I'm studying computer science and only for 6 month, so still learning. And it works now. GREAT! :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because your SQL is broken:

```
SELECT Navn FROM Vare WHERE Stregkode = ) Values('" + streg + "')"
```

What did you expect that `WHERE` clause to do, and what values are you trying to use? It looks like you've got a broken copy/paste from an update command.

Additionally, you shouldn't put values into your SQL like that anyway - you should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks (and to avoid formatting issues etc).

Answer (score 1):

Ya, surely it will give. Why you put the `Values` in your `select` query? which is wrong syntax, Try Now.

```
string query = "SELECT Navn FROM Vare WHERE Stregkode = '" + streg + "'";
```

Comment: So, this will work but you shouldn't recommend something that opens you up SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, @Yuck this is not a query which I have given my self I just modified his code and given back in correct syntax.